# How to accept only some downloads in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

When I click a button on this website, it will offer 4 items for download. I only need 2 of them. Selenium will automatically download all 4 files for me.

But I only want to download the video files, not the text files. How can I tell firefox to not automatically download all of them?

The following code is what I use to fire up the selenium.

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.profile = r"C:\Users\Profiles\osdf86s"
download_dir = r'C:\Users\Downloads'
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
s = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = s, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the preference `"browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"` to `"video/mp4, video/avi",` which tells Firefox to automatically download files.

```
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "video/mp4, video/avi")
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I tell the text files to not download?